# Microsoft all-in-one media keyboard not working with Macbook Bigsur

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, windows, trackpad, big-sur

I have the using the Microsoft all-in-one media keyboard with windows machine and it works fine, but with my macbook, the experience is really bad, it lags and the track pad is jerky/ slow and unpredictable. And none of the gestures work. Many sites show that Microsoft all-in-one keyboard with trackpad is compatible with Mac.

Comment: This is not surprising because Microsoft products usually works better with Windows. Had you tried to use it on another mac / another system?

Comment: Does microsoft provide a kext / system extension / software to use it on mac?

Comment: I didn't see that information anywher

Comment: According to this https://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Wireless-Media-Keyboard-N9Z-00001/dp/B00IICMUWS.  It is compatible with macOS up to version 10.10. So it _may_ be that (if you have a newer macOS) it is not compatible. But Amazon is the only place I found compatibility listings, so take that with a grain of salt